# Show completely MonthCalendar control inside a GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox, monthcalendar

I'm trying to show a month calendar completely inside a groupbox, I read, you can use a Panel and change the poperty AutoScroll into true, but it does not work.

Is there another way to show it or I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The GroupBox control can be goofy to work with, because the Client space will overlap the GroupBox's title, but the DisplayRectangle will adjust correctly the upper left position of the "control space".

So try adjusting the size of the GroupBox using code (I don't think the designer is good at this):

```
groupBox1.AutoSize = false;
monthCalendar1.Location = groupBox1.DisplayRectangle.Location;
int w = monthCalendar1.Size.Width + groupBox1.Padding.Left + 
                                    groupBox1.Padding.Right;
int h = monthCalendar1.Size.Height + groupBox1.DisplayRectangle.Top + 
                                     groupBox1.Padding.Bottom;
groupBox1.ClientSize = new Size(w, h);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with this, regards